# Converting excel Formulas into Python code

Tags: python, excel-formula, equation

There are the equation I used in excel, just wondering how I would translate them into a python script. Not sure on the correct index but the letter number represents the location on the cell.

I am every novice in the python space

Input

| Num | Recover | Return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cate1 | B2 | C2 |
| Cate2 | B3 | C3 |
| Cate3 | B4 | C3 |
| Cate4 | B5 | C5 |

Output

| Category | Return calc |
| --- | --- |
| Cate1 | X1 |
| Cate2 | X2 |
| Cate3 | X3 |
| Cate4 | X4 |
| Cate5 | X5 |

Formulas

```
Cate1[X1] = C2

Cate2[X2] = C2 * (B2 / (B3 + B2)) + C3 * (B3 / (B2 + B3))

Cate3[X3] = C2 * (B2 / (B2 + B3 + B4) + C3 * (B3 / (B2 + B3 + B4)) + C4 * (B4 / (B2 + B3 + B4))

Cate4[X4] =C2*(B2/(B2+B3+B4+B5))+C3*(B3/(B2+B3+B4+B5))+C4*(B4/(B2+B3+B4+B5))+C5*(B5/(B2+B3+B4+B5))
```

Comment: What kind of help do you need? That's not clear from your question. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question?

Comment: Are you literally reading your data from Excel?  What package are you using?  Your formulae would be easy to do in Python, as long as you have the data in an array of some kind.

Comment: @TimRoberts,  The data is in a pandas data frame.  Apologies, I just have it in an excel format because aid in explaining the formula.

Comment: The math is not hard, but this is not a code-writing service.  You need to make a good effort to solve the problem, then come to us with any problems.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I would love to give it a go, just not sure how I could do it. 

So far I have used df. expanding().sum() to calculate the expanding sums and turned this into a column. 

then trying to use .rolling to divide against the expanding sum but this is where I am getting incorrect values.  

I have attempted using for loop with nested if statements but I get lost when making nested loops and if statements.

Comment: Again, post what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take advantage of the series.  The denominator in each row element is the same (sum of the Bs).  So, for each row, find the sum of the Bs, and then take Cn * Bn / sum-of-bs.  Note that this even applies to the first row, which is actually C2 * B2 / B2.

In this code, I'm assuming "array" has your data, with columns first, so `array[1]` is column B and `array[2]` is column C.  That's backwards from numpy's usual ordering, but it matches what pandas does.

```
for row in range(4):
    sums = 0
    denom = 0
    for n in range(row+1):
        denom = array[1][n]
    for n in range(row+1):
        sums += array[2][n] * array[1][n] / denom
    array[0][row] = sums
```